# ¿Por qué da error si intentas sobrescribir HashCode() y Equals() en una clase Enum?

Tags: java, hash, enum

Estoy buscando información al respecto pero no la encuentro. A ver si podéis ayudarme.

Si Java trata los **enum** como si fueran *clases*, ¿por que no permite sobrescribir **HashCode** y **Equals**?

Gracias de antemano y un saludo

Comment: Cual es el código que estas realizando?

Comment: ¿De dónde te has sacado que Java trate los enums como clases? ¿Cómo vas a sobreescribir un método de una clase padre si los enums no admiten herencia con otras clases? Aunque un enum puede implementar interfaces, no se puede extender de una clase, y el método hashCode() y equals() son métodos de la clase Object. Un enum es un enum y una clase es una clase. Tienen algún parecido, pero son cosas diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque el codigo compilado de un enum si se convierte en una clase, estos no requieren de `getHashCode()` y `equals()` debido a que *nunca comparas instancias de los `enum`*, sino **el valor de sus propiedades**.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos un enum:

```
public enum Color{
   BLUE, RED, WHITE
}
```

Que compilado seria:

```
public final class Color extends java.lang.Enum<Color>
{
  public static final int BLUE = 1, RED = 2, WHITE = 3;
}
```

Si quieres comparar si un valor del enum es igual otro, siempre comparas el valor de la propiedad, no la instancia del enum:

```
Color blue = Color.BlUE;
boolean equals = blue === Color.WHITE; // Se comprar el valor con la propiedad WHITE
```

Que traducido seria:

```
int blue = Color.BlUE;
boolean equals = blue == Color.BLUE; // comparando las propiedades estaticas de la clase Color.
```

Por lo que no se necesitan esos metodos en los enum. De eso la razon que no te permite implementarlos.